# CollapsingToolbarLayout with 2 pin layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I write this code but not works properly. I want the imageview collapse in parallax mode, and toolbar and relative layout pin at top of the screen. they pin and don't scroll but the relative layout cover on the toolbar. I want relative layout stay bottom of toolbar and don't scroll.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">



                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:text="New Button"
                    android:id="@+id/button" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:text="New Button"
                    android:id="@+id/button2" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:text="New Button"
                    android:id="@+id/button3" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:text="New Button"
                    android:id="@+id/button4" />
            </LinearLayout>



    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:background="#44C8F5">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/CollapsingToolbarLayout"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/header_image"
                android:src="@drawable/header_test"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">


            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom">


                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="@dimen/footer_appbar_padding"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="New Text"
                                android:id="@+id/textView" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="New Text"
                                android:id="@+id/textView2" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                            android:src="@drawable/faranesh_logo"
                            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="New Button"
                        android:id="@+id/button5"
                        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

                </FrameLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar;
private ImageView headerImage;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private Drawer result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawer_item_custom_container_drawer);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


    AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener mListener = new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
            headerImage.setImageAlpha((int)( 255*(((double)(headerImage.getHeight()+verticalOffset)/headerImage.getHeight()))));


        }


    };
    ((AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appBar)).addOnOffsetChangedListener(mListener);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```